# If span exists add class to link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links that I retrieve by AJAX. I parse the links and append them to a div. However sometimes there is a 'span' just after the 'a' that I need to take into consideration.

The code looks like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/link1" class="list-link">Link1 </a></li>
   <li><a href="/link1" class="list-link">Link1 </a><span class="sometimes-here"></span></li>
   <li><a href="/link1" class="list-link">Link1 </a></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

So what I want to do is to locate when a 'li' consist of a span and then apply that class ('sometimes-here') as an additional class to the 'a'.

I should elaborate what I need a bit as you only answered how to filter out all the 'li' that doesn't consist of the span. I want the end result to look like this.

```
<a href="/link1" class="list-link">Link1 </a>
<a href="/link1" class="list-link sometimes-here">Link1 </a>
<a href="/link1" class="list-link">Link1 </a>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$('li:has(span)').find('a').addClass('yourClass');
```

Comment: or maybe, `$('li:has(span) a').addClass('yourClass');` as well.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan yes! your answer will be better! i correct it

Comment: I think you guys are missing the point. I think he wants *whatever the class in the span is* to be added as a class to the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li:has(span) a').addClass('yourClass');
```